# Playback Exception on m3u8 url in android flutter with just_audio

Tags: android, flutter, just-audio

I am not able to play the m3u8 audio url with just audio in android platform.everything works perfect in ios.

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:614)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:92)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1017)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12283):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E/AudioPlayer(12283): TYPE_SOURCE: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
I/ExoPlayerImpl(12283): Release 616d8a [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.7] [a53x, SM-A536B, samsung, 33] [goog.exo.core, goog.exo.exoplayer, goog.exo.decoder, goog.exo.datasource, goog.exo.extractor]
```

this is the error I am getting in android.Please help me out to resolve this.
the audio url is [this](https://api.moodstream.anothercircus.com/api/m3u8?mood=4)